# share data between app by content provider is not work

Tags: android, kotlin, android-contentprovider

I create First App and his name "provides" and I use SQLite Database for create table and insert data to a table and everything is work.
and I create Second App and his name "consumes" his app is responsible to receive data from my first app then I create Content Provider in the first app and this is code :

```
class Provider : ContentProvider() {
    private lateinit var db: LoginSqliteHelper
    override fun onCreate(): Boolean {
        db = LoginSqliteHelper(context!!)
        return true
    }

    override fun query(
        uri: Uri,
        projection: Array<out String>?,
        selection: String?,
        selectionArgs: Array<out String>?,
        sortOrder: String?
    ): Cursor? {
        return db.readableDatabase.query(
            ConstantValue.Table_Name,
            projection,
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            null,
            null,
            sortOrder
        )
    }

    override fun getType(uri: Uri): String? {
        return "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.example.storge.provider"
    }

    override fun insert(uri: Uri, values: ContentValues?): Uri? {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun delete(uri: Uri, selection: String?, selectionArgs: Array<out String>?): Int {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun update(
        uri: Uri,
        values: ContentValues?,
        selection: String?,
        selectionArgs: Array<out String>?
    ): Int {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}
```

then I Create Provider in the manifest

```
<provider
            android:name=".sqlite.Provider"
            android:authorities="com.example.storage"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />
```

for information the package name to first app is "com.example.storage"
then I receive data from my first app in the second app by this method :

```
val uri = Uri.parse("content://com.example.storge")
        val cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null)
        if (cursor != null){
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                for (i in 0 until cursor.columnCount) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "$i - ${cursor.getColumnName(i)} ${cursor.getString(i)}")
                }
            }
            cursor.close()
        }
```

but the cursor is null , I do not know why null !?

The first application works effectively, but when I run the second application, it does not receive any data from the first application. What is the reason?

Comment: So the second apps name is Content Provider but the content provider is in the first app? If so then that is very confusing.  There is the one that provides and the one that consumes. Please rename an rephrase to prevent confusing.

Comment: The first application is the one that contains the provider, so I want the data to be received in the second application.

In short, I want to send data from the first application to the second application using the content provider. I did this as you saw the code, but when the data reaches the second application, an null value arrives.

Comment: Please edit your post like you were asked to do.